# Ubuntu 18.04 won’t boot, disk full

Tags: boot, 18.04, disk-management

I was downloading a huge (280GB) torrent to my external drive. I had no idea I’m stuffing the Ubuntu 18.04 partition in any way. I rebooted and the Ubuntu won’t start, giving me „Start job is running for hold until boot process finishes up” error and freezing.

I have access to the Windows 7 partition, the recovery menu and the terminal, but I don’t know my way around it. So far I tried the „free up memory” option, but it did nothing.

Help!

Comment: Is Ubuntu on the external drive or is it just data?  Can probably use an Ubuntu live USB and delete some non important stuff.  Torrent apps usually have a setting to check for disk space.  Would check the disks app on live USB and see the size and amount of  free space on your partitions to get an idea what's happening.  Should try to keep about 15 to 20% free.

Comment: Just data, Ubuntu is on a main disk partition.

Comment: Think two different things happen.  If external is just full of data, might take a long time to load when booting, quit everything, shutdown and remove data drive and reboot.  Does torrent app load at boot time?

Comment: The external has over 1TB of free space left... No, the torrent app won’t boot start, and the external drive is already disconnected. Still, no boot.

Comment: Could also be a start job gone wonky, but that is for better people than I.  Would google start job's name if you have it.  'ubuntu job name not starting'

Comment: It think it’s just some kind of temporary files overload. It’s just, I don’t know how to clean it from the command line.